# Android SIP Module to Appcelerator

Tags: android, module, sip, appcelerator, voip

I'm working on appcelerator doing a sip module for android.

I'm using a Mac OS X version 10.8.5 , Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.3.201309132423 I'm testing on a device galaxy ace android 2.3.6

According to the documentation of android developers , the first thing to do is create a new instance of SipManager . http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

`SipManager mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(Context context);`

how do I get the context?

According appcelerator wiki is:

`TiApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();`

being :

```
SipManager mSipManager =     
SipManager.newInstance(TiApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
```

I have not problems compiling the module, or the application that uses it , but this does not work because mSipManager is null

I did not put all the code of the module, because I think the problem is in the Context parameter.

I tried many ways  but always returns null.

Could someone test on your device and see if it returns the same?
I don't know what to do, I need help please.
thanks

Comment: hi can you provide me any example?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get the Context of the Application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

   private static Context context;

   public void onCreate(){
       super.onCreate();
       MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
   }

   public static Context getAppContext() {
       return MyApplication.context;
   }
```

}

**Or For Resolving the context Error You can Have the following**

```
Context context;
SipManager mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(context);
```